# Perl Regex: Matching text with optional multi-line

Tags: regex, arrays, perl

I'm trying to extract object files from Linux Make files. Here are some examples:

Intel E1000E:

```
e1000e-objs := 82571.o ich8lan.o 80003es2lan.o \
       mac.o manage.o nvm.o phy.o \
       param.o ethtool.o netdev.o ptp.o
```

Chelsio T3:

```
cxgb3-objs := cxgb3_main.o ael1002.o vsc8211.o t3_hw.o mc5.o \
       xgmac.o sge.o l2t.o cxgb3_offload.o aq100x.o
```

Atheros ALX:

```
alx-objs := main.o ethtool.o hw.o
```

How can I make a regular expression that returns what is after := considering that having multiple lines is optional and there could be more than two lines? Note that the backslashes are part of the Makefile content.

I know only how to specify manually the number of new lines with something like:

```
$obj_files_no_ext = "e1000";
my @filestmp = ($Makefile_contents =~ m/$obj_files_no_ext-objs\s*[\+\:]= (.*)\\\s*\n(.*)/g);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with this:

```
$obj_files_no_ext-objs\s*:=\s*((?:(?:[^\s\\]*?\.o)[\s\n\r\\]*)+)
```

This will capture all object files that belong to a certain `$obj_files_no_ext` in group 1.

Comment: $obj_files_no_ext is a variable. I've tried to edit the post to remove the first \ but I needed to change at least 6 characters.

Comment: @PeterSenna I don't understand, could you please explain further ?

Comment: `$obj_files_no_ext` is a variable and in the example regex of OP will in fact be substitute by `e1000`.

Comment: @Jerry I understand this part, but I don't understand the rest of the sentence ?

Comment: @Sniffer I would remove the first backslash, so it will be ok.

Comment: @PeterSenna Ahhh OK. Sorry for that one I missed it, I don't use PERL so I though you had to escape it. Anyway So everything is OK ?

Comment: @Sniffer To be honest, I'm not sure either for that other part xD

Answer (score 2):

You can try with this pattern:

```
(?>$obj_files_no_ext-objs\s*:=|\G)\s*\K(?>[^\s.]++|\.(?!o(?:\s|$)))++\.o
```

pattern details:

```
(?>                    # open an atomic group
    $obj_files_no_ext  # radical
    -objs\s*:=         
  |                    # OR
    \G                 # contiguous match
)                      # close the atomic group
\s*\K                  # optional spaces and reset all the match
(?>                    # open an atomic group (filename possible characters)
    [^\s.]++           # all that is not a white character or a dot (1+ times)
  |                    # OR
    \.(?!o(?:\s|$))    # a dot not followed by "o", a space or the string end 
)++                    # repeat the atomic group one or more times
\.o
```

example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $Makefile_contents = q{e1000e-objs := 82571.o ich8lan.o 80003es2lan.o 
   mac.o manage.o nvm.o phy.o 
   param.o ethtool.o netdev.o ptp.o};

my $obj_files_no_ext = "e1000e";
my $reg = qr/(?>$obj_files_no_ext-objs\s*:=|\G)\s*\K(?>[^\s.]++|\.(?!o(?:\s|$)))++\.o/;
my @filestmp =  $Makefile_contents =~ /$reg/g;
print join(" ",@filestmp);
```

Comment: On my test it is returning only what is before the first \, also in some files there could be more than one line starting with e1000e-objs +=, this is why I'm using ($str =~ m/.../g). The pattern details are very instrutive. Thanks.

Comment: @PeterSenna: Yes, because (as you can read in the example code), I was assuming that the slashes were here only to illustrate the fact that there are newlines, and are not really here. It's strange that these slashes are in your datas, perhaps could you avoid this before?

Comment: @PeterSenna: If you want you can replace `\G` by `\G\s*\\?` to correct the problem.

Comment: yes I could have specified this before, sorry. I've added a note to the question.